# Passing a Product ID to PayPal Button

Tags: javascript, paypal, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a bunch of products, all with the same price (I can't create a PayPal button for each product because there will be thousands of them).

Is there a way to pass the product ID to PayPal so that I know which product the customer purchased?

For example: I've got a product page at www.mysite.com/products/1 ...where 1 is the product ID.

There are also product pages at www.mysite.com/products/2 etc...

There's a PayPal button on each product page. Is there a way to pass the product ID to PayPal so that I know which product was purchased?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `custom` when `item_number` is available.

> item_number    See description.
>   Pass-through variable for you to track product or service purchased or the contribution made. The value you specify is passed back to you upon payment completion. This variable is required if you want PayPal to track inventory or track profit and loss for the item the button sells.
>   127 characters max

From https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your PayPal button you can pass a `custom` [variable](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) that you can use for your back-end processing.

[image]

You will need to grab your product id(from the GET URL, might use js to do that) and pass the same to the custom variable inside your button code.

Later you could use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) so that paypal would send you notification of the item purchased along with the custom variable that you have passed.

Comment: is the custom variable just added as an html property like this? `<a href="my-paypal-button-url.com" custom="product_id_variable"></a>`